# set cookie for mac in php

Tags: php, cookies, safari

I want set cookie for mac in php.Here is my code:

```
setcookie("COOKIETEST","1",time() +3600*24*365,"/",".testingdomain.com");
```

It is work fine on chrome & firefox but problem to set cookie for safari web browser, mac & iphone devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the Safari Browsers are the issue by design, but probably the security settings you have defined in them?

- There is on OS X f.eg. a setting in Safari `Privacy > Cookies and Website data`
  which by default may prevent creating a cookie. Try adjusting this
  setting and see if it will work.
- Same setting should be available on iOS Devices in `Settings App > Safari`